# AWS Glue crawling JSON lines data in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have this type of data in my S3:

```
{"version":"0","id":"c1d9e9a4-25a2-a0d8-2fa4-b062efec98c4","detail-type":"OneTypeee","source":"OneSource","account":"123456789","time":"2021-01-17T12:35:17Z","region":"eu-central-1","resources":[],"detail":{"Key1":"Value1"}}
{"version":"0","id":"c13879a4-2h32-a0d8-9m33-b03jsh3cxxj4","detail-type":"OtherType","source":"SomeMagicSource","account":"123456789","time":"2021-01-17T12:36:17Z","region":"eu-central-1","resources":[],"detail":{"Key2":"Value2", "Key22":"Value22"}}
{"version":"0","id":"gi442233-3y44a0d8-9m33-937rjd74jdddj","detail-type":"MoreTypes","source":"SomeMagicSource2","account":"123456789","time":"2021-01-17T12:45:17Z","region":"eu-central-1","resources":[],"detail":{"MagicKey":"MagicValue", "Foo":"Bar"}}
```

Please note, I have added new lines to make it more readable. In reality, Kinesis Firehose produces these batches with no newlines.

When I try to run an AWS Glue crawler on this type of data, it only crawls the first JSON line and that's it. I know this because when I run Athena SQL queries, I always get only one (first) result.

How do I make a glue crawler correctly crawl through this data and make a correct schema so I could query all of that data?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and for me the reason was that json records were being written to S3 bucket without next line character: `\n`.

Make sure your json records are written with `\n` appended at the end. In case of java, something like this:

```
PutRecordRequest request = new PutRecordRequest()
    .withRecord(new Record().withData(ByteBuffer.wrap((json + "\n").getBytes())))
    .withDeliveryStreamName(streamName);
amazonKinesis.putRecordAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to run a crawler through JSON lines data, but simply specifying in the Glue Table Serde properties that the data is JSON worked for me. Glue automatically splits the JSON by newline and I can query the data in my Glue Jobs.

Here's what my table's properties look like. Additionally, my json lines data was compressed, so here you can ignore the `compressionType` property.
[image: glue table configuration]

Comment: Did this work as expected? For me, Glue only reads the first JSON object in the file.

Comment: Same for me, and it's correctly marked as JSON